# Rails console not working even after updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run `rails console`. I have tried everything suggested on SO. I have `libreadline-6` installed. My ruby version is 2.1.1 and irb is 0.9.6.

```
/home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `require'
from /home/xamroc/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions?

Also, I am using rbenv to manage my ruby versions.

Comment: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby-on-rails/fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console/

Comment: I am using rbenv to manage my ruby versions. The post is using RVM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libreadline and also the -dev package and then you need to recompile ruby. When your using rvm you should always run

```
rvm requirements
```

first and then download and compile ruby. If your using rvm then you can run

```
rvm reinstall <version>
```

to do this.

// Also see: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby/readline-in-ruby-with-rbenv/

Comment: I have the -dev package installed as well. Do you happen to know how to reinstall using rbenv?